# css: attr(data) with counter

Tags: html, css

I have this code, I want the counter which will be take info from `attr`, every number will began from `data` info of the element.

**html**

```
<ul>
     <li data="info1"></li>
     <li data="info2"></li>
     <li data="info3"></li>
     <li data="info4"></li>
     <li data="info5"></li>
     <li data="info6"></li>
     <li data="info7"></li>
     <li data="info8"></li>
 </ul>
```

**css**

```
body{
    counter-reset: section;
}
ul li:before{
    counter-increment: section;
    content:"it from data - " counter(section);
}
```

[Result](http://jsfiddle.net/EtzDV/4/)

Comment: I want for example in data="My Article", the the counter automaticly put numbers after it.

Comment: So like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EtzDV/6/)?

Comment: Yes I have already find answer too.. my question was stupid.. :))

Comment: The attribute `data` is invalid in all versions of HTML. Use [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) instead, e.g. `data-i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for this question, the answer was simple

```
 ul li:before{
        counter-increment: section;
        content:attr(data) "- " counter(section);
    }
```

[Click here for result](http://jsfiddle.net/ffJMJ/)

Question is closed